# Cannot use GPU with tensorflow dlerror:libcudnn.so.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, ubuntu-18.04

When I'm trying to run the MNIST project to test if it worked I got the following notification on the terminal.

> Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.7'; dlerror:
> libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
> /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64

My system:
Ubuntu 18.04, tensorflow 2.2, cuda 10.1, cudnn 7.6.5

What I've tried:

1. Modifying the LD_LIBRARY_PATH with the following command:

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

calling an echo on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH will result

> /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64

2. Fixing the symlink on /usr/local/cuda/lib64 using the following commands:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so
sudo rm /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.7
cd /usr/local/cuda/lib64/
sudo ln -s libcudnn.so.7.6.5 libcudnn.so.7
sudo ln -s libcudnn.so.7 libcudnn.so
```

checking the result using ls -lha libcudnn* will result in

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13 Mar  6 14:52 libcudnn.so -> libcudnn.so.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   17 Mar  6 14:52 libcudnn.so.7 -> libcudnn.so.7.6.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 409M Mar  6 14:41 libcudnn.so.7.6.5
```

3. Installing the cuda-toolkit again still yield the same result.

Comment: Try This `sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64`. And also take a look at several workarounds are discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20271). Thanks!

Comment: I already solved it. I am an idiot, since I forgot I used docker and should've installed the cudnn on the container instead of the host machine.